# Any function equivalent to oracle sql's DBMS_UTILITY.get_hash_value() in Transact-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

On searching msdn, I found a built-in function called HASHBYTES(). Not sure if that can be used to get a result that DBMS_UTILITY.get_hash_value() gives in oracle.I am using SQL Server 2008. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HASHBYTES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) is close, but uses presets for certain algorithms (e.g. SHA1 or MD5)

You can't choose the base or length like you can with [DBMS_UTILITY.GET_HASH_VALUE()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10802/d_util.htm#1003647)

You may have to roll your own to emulate it exactly but I'd see this as a backwards step...

Answer (score 0):

Comparison in SQL built-in functions in Oracle and SQL Server on below given link

http://dotnet-bm.blogspot.in/2013/08/comparison-in-sql-built-in-functions-in.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.